# identifying duplicate row sets

Tags: oracle

I have  table that looks like the following.

```
   create table Testing(  
    inv_num varchar2(100),  
    po_num  varchar2(100),  
    line_num varchar2(100)  
    )
```

data with the following.

```
Insert into Testing (INV_NUM,PO_num,line_num) values ('19782594','P0254836',1);  
Insert into Testing (INV_NUM,PO_num,line_num) values ('19782594','P0254836',1);  
Insert into Testing (INV_NUM,PO_num,line_num) values ('19968276','P0254836',1);  
Insert into Testing (INV_NUM,PO_num,line_num) values ('19968276','P0254836',1);
```

what i'm trying to do is identify the multiple items within the table with the same PO_num but different inv_num.

I have try this

```
  SELECT    
            T1.inv_num,  
            T1.Po_num,  
            T1.LINE_num  ,  
            count(*) over( partition by   
            T1.inv_num)myRecords  
        FROM testing T1  
         where  T1.Po_num  = 'P0254836'  
         group by   
            T1.inv_num,  
            T1.Po_num,  
            T1.LINE_num  
            order by t1.inv_num
```

but this those not give me the desired end result.

I would like to end with  the following.

```
INV_NUM PO_NUM      LINE_NUM     Myrecords
19782594    P0254836    1     1
19782594    P0254836    1     1
19968276    P0254836    1     2
19968276    P0254836    1     2
```

Where I'm going wrong? I really like  to  identify the change in INV_NUM for that po.

Please be aware this is part of a much larger project and I have only picked a small subset to show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
SELECT
  inv_num
  , po_num
  , line_num
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY inv_num) "MyRecords"
FROM (
    SELECT
      po_num
      , inv_num
      , line_num
      , COUNT(line_num) OVER (PARTITION BY po_num, inv_num ORDER BY NULL) cnt
    FROM testing
)
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

returns

```
|  INV_NUM |   PO_NUM | LINE_NUM | MYRECORDS |
|----------|----------|----------|-----------|
| 19782594 | P0254836 |        1 |         1 |
| 19782594 | P0254836 |        1 |         1 |
| 19968276 | P0254836 |        1 |         2 |
| 19968276 | P0254836 |        1 |         2 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bb05/10/0)

Comment: That gives me 2 and 2 for the count. I would like to identify the first set as set 1 and the second set as set 2. per my end result.

Comment: And you want the duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT inv_num,
       po_num,
       line_num,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY inv_num) AS rn
  FROM testing
```

Comment: this is pretty close but it needs to include Po_num for counting the sets. So if I include `Insert into Testing (INV_NUM,PO_num,line_num) values ('19968279','P0254837',1);` this would fail.

Comment: what do you expect ad `Myrecords` for this new row?